# Как исключить папки к которым пользователь не имеет доступ Python os

Tags: python

Есть функция которая перебирает директории и в процессе натыкается на такие как `C:\\$Recycle.Bin\\` `.` `os.access()` на каждый флаг выводит `True`, но если передать этот путь в `os.listdir()` то выдает ошибку `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе:` Как исключить подобные директории в `Python`?

Comment: Ловить ошибку и игнорировать ее

Comment: Интересно увидеть, как вы используете метод `os.access()`, какие значения принимает `mode`-параметр при вызове. Поскольку данный аспект освещен в самой [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)

Comment: @Dmitry os.access('C:\\$Recycle.Bin\\S-1-5-18', mode=os.X_OK) и так с os.R_OK, os.F_OK, os.w_OK

Comment: @lord_lerny довольно странное поведение, я проверил у себя на машине. Все флаги вернули False. Ввод `os.access("C:\\$Recycle.Bin\\S-1-5-18'", os.X_OK)`, вывод `False`. Хотя тот же `os.access("C:\\$Recycle.Bin", os.W_OK) ` возвращает `True`. [Можете показать код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1324987/edit)

Comment: @Dmitry (я слегка ошибся, я писал про C:\\$Recycle.Bin\\S-1-5-18, а не про C:\\$Recycle.Bin\\)
import os
print(os.path.exists('C:\\$Recycle.Bin\\S-1-5-18'))
print(os.access('C:\\$Recycle.Bin\\S-1-5-18', mode=os.X_OK))
print(os.listdir('C:\\$Recycle.Bin\\S-1-5-18'))
#True
#True
#PermissionError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе